# Filled data structure with unique objects that does not have same member variables

Tags: c++, lambda, qt

I have in-house template like `QList` which creates a list of all objects of, say, `Book`.

This list contains many objects of `Book`. `Book` has member variable called `BookTitle` and in some cases objects have same value for `BookTitle`.

Now I am thinking of writing a function which contains objects of `Book` having unique book title. My function is working fine but I am wondering if I can improve it or maybe use a lambda for it. Can someone please shed light on it?

```
void createUniqueList{
unique_book_collection->deleteAll(); // deleteAll is in-house function 

Book* bookfirst = bookRecord->collection.at(0);
unique_book_collection->addRecord( bookfirst); // addRecord func in-house 

for( Book* l_book : bookRecord->collection())
{

         bool found = false;
        if(unique_book_collection != nullptr )
        {
        for( Book* l_uniqueBookRecord: unique_book_collection->collection() )
        {
            if( _uniqueBookRecord->bookTitle->description() == l_book->bookTitle->description() )
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        }
        if( found == false )
        {
            unique_book_collection->addRecord( l_book );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collections seem to implement the standard container interface correctly since they work with range-based `for`s. This means that you can use standard functions from `<algorithm>`. Keeping your algorithm the same, your function becomes:

```
void createUniqueList() {
    unique_book_collection->deleteAll();

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    auto &col = unique_book_collection->collection();

    for(Book *b : bookRecord->collection())
        if(std::find_if(begin(col), end(col), [&](Book const *b2) {
            return b2->bookTitle->description() == b->bookTitle->description();
        }) == end(col))
            unique_book_collection->addRecord(b);
}
```

Notes:

- `if(unique_book_collection != nullptr)` has been removed. You dereferenced it earlier in the function and didn't change it in the meantime, so it cannot be null.
- The first book has no special treatment : it won't be found in the empty list, and will be added as any other.